# Overriding vertical-align required for superscript but applied by table attributes

Tags: css, html-table, superscript

Below is my code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="31%" align="center" valign="middle">
<a href="http://google.com/"></a> 
</td>
<td width="69%" valign="top">
Terms and conditions
<sup>#</sup>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

`superscript` is not working (# is not at the top. Its in the same line as of the Terms & conditions text).

My guess is `vertical-align` of `superscript` is getting overridden by `table` attributes.

Below is the default usage stylesheet of `table` attributes captured from Web developer. I have also captured for `sup`. I don't see that its values are striken off in Web developer.

```
tbody {
display: table-row-group;
vertical-align: middle;
border-color: inherit;
}

tr {
display: table-row;
vertical-align: inherit;
border-color: inherit;
}

td, th {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: inherit;
}

td[Attributes Style] {
width: 31%;
text-align: -webkit-center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

sup {
vertical-align: super;
font-size: smaller;
}
```

If I place `sup` outside `table` attribute, it works fine. How can I get my `sup` working inside `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valign="top"` is the cause. If you remove it the superscript will work.

```
<td width="69%">
    Terms and conditions<sup>#</sup>
</td>
```

Or if you want to maintain the v-align, encapsulate:

```
<td width="69%" valign="top">
    <span>Terms and conditions<sup>#</sup></span>
</td>
```